# How To Exchange Information Between Classes

Tags: java

I have a class that gets password-hash from a SQL database and there is another class which takes password from the user. How do I exchange password between the two classes? Is data access using objects follows encapsulation in java?

Comment: You really need to define "safe" here for the question to be answerable.

Comment: I need it to be safe in sense that any user is not able to access password from the application.

Comment: If it's a hash, they can't get the password from that anyway. But what sort of user are we talking about, and what sort of application? Are you expecting them to be able to run the app on their own machine? If so, they will be able to access whatever is in memory...

Comment: To be true, I am pretty much a noobie as far as security is concerned. So, can you explain to me how this information can be accessed from memory. I'm building a login system based on GUI java application. So, I need to make sure it is secure enough to be used by a person on a daily basis.

Comment: Um, if the user is running the code, and they have complete control over their system, then they can use any number of system level debuggers to see exactly what's in memory. To be honest, this question feels too broad to me - you should really be thinking about specific attack vectors that you're worrying about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should not propagate password across layers and should use approach followed by spring-security where passwords are encrypted both in DB and from UI to server. For reference you can follow https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/

You don't need to implement spring-security to use this functionality but just use associated classes to achieve same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your class should get the password from the user and hash it in place.

Then it could call your DAO class passing it the hash to compare with the database to validate the user.

Passing the password around is poor practice.